# How to apply conditions in my filter

Tags: ocaml

I have the following function that displays lines of a previously generated maze:

```
let rec print_line_2 maze i j =
  match maze.width - j with
  | 0 -> ()
  | _ -> match (Maze.access maze j i).doors.(1) with
    | Closed -> if j < (maze.width - 1)
      then Printf.printf "---+"; print_line_2 maze i (j + 1)
      else Printf.printf "----"; print_line_2 maze i (j + 1);
    | Opened -> if j < (maze.width - 1)
      then Printf.printf "   +"; print_line_2 maze i (j + 1)
      else Printf.printf "    "; print_line_2 maze i (j + 1);
```

But I have a syntax error on the first `else`. How may I add conditions to my filter to make it work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because

```
if x then
  a;
  b;
else
  c;
  d;
```

is actually parsed as

```
if x then
  a;
b;
else <-- error
```

You should add parentheses (or `begin` `end` which is the same):

```
if x then begin
  a;
  b;
end else begin
  c;
  d;
end
```

Comment: So you should write _if x then begin a; b end else begin c; d end_ or _if x then (a; b) else (c; d)_

Answer (score 0):

Usually, I suggest to use `when` guards:

```
open Printf

let rec print_line_2 maze i j =
  match maze.width - j with
  | 0 -> ()
  | _ -> match (Maze.access maze j i).doors.(1) with
    | Closed when j < maze.width - 1 ->
      printf "---+"; print_line_2 maze i (j + 1)
    | Closed -> 
      printf "----"; print_line_2 maze i (j + 1)
    | Opened when j < maze.width - 1 -> 
      printf "   +"; print_line_2 maze i (j + 1)
    | Opened -> 
      printf "    "; print_line_2 maze i (j + 1)
```

But looking at your code, I see repeating patterns, with only few pieces of code depending on the branch conditions. Looks like that you're missing an opportunity for abstraction, for example:

```
let rec print_line_2 maze i j =
  let print wall = print_string wall; print_line_2 maze i (j+1) in
  if maze.width - j <> 0 then match (Maze.access maze j i).doors.(1) with
    | Closed -> if j < maze.width - 1 then print "---+" else print "----" 
    | Opened -> if j < maze.width - 1 then print "   +" else print "    "
```